# Incremental ID and push data as number - google Firebase and react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am using google firebase to store and retrieve data for one of my application. I'm successfully able to push and retrieve the data to and from database. What I'm trying is to set a incremental ID to the document Auto ID of collection.

```
let db_push = firestore.database().ref('Table').push();
      db_push.set({
        name:name,
        age:age,
        location:location
      })
```

I'm able to push the data but the ID is setting something like `afbghy67kju`. And the `age` data pushing as a string. How can I set the auto numbering ID and push the `age` var as a number?

Comment: There is no provided auto numbering capability in Realtime Database.  You will need to build a solution.  If you use a javascript number type, it will show up as a number in the database.  If you provide as string, it will appear as a string, even if it looks like a number.  Convert the age string to a number first in your code.

Comment: Yes. I'm able to resolve the number problem. How the ID can be controlled? Is there any way to control it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push()` will create a random id for every node, if you don't want a random id then you need to add your own implementation. Another way also to use the unique `userId` instead of `push()`:

```
firebase.database().ref('Table/' + userId).set({
  name:name,
  age:age,
  location:location
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: This actually worked. I have added some logic to generate userId based on no of users. Thanks